# UART flow controls

Tags: uart

I confused little bit regarding flow control. I have two devices, one is having uart flow control pins(RTS and CTS) but other device don't have. The device which having uart fow control pin i configured as hardware flow control. So device(which doesn't have flow control)  need to send 1(asserted) to before sending data, then it need to check the RTS pin(device which having flowcontrol) by device( which doesn't have flow control). then it will send data. Is my understanding is correct?

2)What is difference between CTS bar and CTS

Comment: I think this should be asked at [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Flow control requires that both ends support it.  If one end does not have HW flow control pins, then you cannot use HW flow control at all.  You may have to look into software flow control, i.e. XON/XOFF.  If you're transmitting binary data, then you'd have "escape" the data that matches the XON & XOFF values.  In "CTS bar" the "bar" usually means inverted logic, i.e. low is TRUE.